# Flask Testing a put request with custom headers

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-restful, flask-testing

Im trying to test a PUT request in my Flask app, using flasks test client. 
Everything looks good to me but i keep getting 400 BAD request.

I tried the same request using POSTMAN and I get the response back.

Here is the code

```
 from flask import Flask 
 app = Flask(__name__) 
 data = {"filename": "/Users/resources/rovi_source_mock.csv"}
 headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
 api = "http://localhost:5000/ingest"
 with app.test_client() as client:
    api_response = client.put(api, data=data, headers=headers)
 print(api_response)
```

**Output**

```
Response streamed [400 BAD REQUEST]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do need to actually encode the data to JSON:

```
import json

with app.test_client() as client:
    api_response = client.put(api, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Setting `data` to a dictionary treats that as a regular form request, so each key-value pair would be encoded into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` content, if you had used either content type. As it is, your data is entirely ignored instead.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is simpler to just pass the data using the `json` parameter instead of the `data` parameter:

```
reponse = test_client.put(
    api, 
    json=data,
)
```

Quoting from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/):

> Passing the json argument in the test client methods sets the request
>   data to the JSON-serialized object and sets the content type to
>   application/json.